# How to connect js script from html to Django static

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have new Django project with frontend, initially written not for Django at all, so I cannot connect this script:

```
<script>
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).
    src='js/main_script.js?r='+Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999999999999);
</script>
```

The file `js/main_script.js` is located in static folder, other `js` scripts are loaded as intended. And as I understand this script prevents caching for some reason.

So, what am I missing in that part? Thanks in advance for any clarifications

Comment: What is the purpose of `Math.random()*99999999999999999999`?

Comment: @roganjosh i think it is hand made version of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage

Comment: @roganjosh, I've found it on stackoverflow, apparently used to prevent caching though i'm not an author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove those `+Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999999999999)` part and use proper solution for static files caching control

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage

*UPD in response to comments below*

Suppose we have

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/web/chick_static/'
STATIC_URL = '/chick-static/'
```

Then when we use [static template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) Django transforms
from

```
<script src="{% static 'js/main_script.js' %}"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/chick-static/js/main_script.js"></script>
```

Also Django will be looking for file in `/var/web/chick_static/` directory.

Comment: but, at least for understanding, why without static-way of loading this script it works while opening .html file, but at Django doesn’t?

Comment: @Chickenfresh i've updated answer, plz check if it is understandable, if not then feel free to ask for more details.